# How to debug slow VPN transfer speeds

Tags: vpn, pptp

I have following network setup, two machines on different ISPs, in different cities.

```
+----------------------------+           +------------------------------+
| HOME                       |           | REMOTE                       |
| ISP: 50mbit up/down        | +-------> | ISP: 200mbit down/20mbit up  |
| SCP: 50mbit up/20mbit down |           | SCP: 50mbit down/20mbit up   |
| VPN: 33mbit up/6mbit down  | <-------+ | VPN: 33mbit down/6mbit up    |
|                            |           |                              |
+----------------------------+           +------------------------------+
```

At HOME I have 50mbit upload and download (measured by speedtest.net) and at REMOTE I have 200 mbit download and 20 mbit upload. HOME is Win10 VPN client and the REMOTE is `pptpd` on Ubuntu Server 16.04. The `pptpd` is using MS-CHAPv2 128bit encryption, but the CPU doesn't show any significant load.

- When uploading data over **internet** from HOME to REMOTE I get full 50mbit using SCP.
- When downloading data over **internet** from REMOTE to HOME I get full 20mbit using SCP.
- When uploading data over **VPN** from HOME to REMOTE I get 33 mbit using SCP.
- When downloading downloading data over **VPN** from REMOTE to HOME I get only 6mbit using SCP.

Originally I have notices the issue with Samba, but when I switched to SCP over VPN, the speed is still only 6mbit, so it seems the protocol doesn't play a role.

**Network setup info**
REMOTE is on gigabit LAN. 
HOME is on WiFi 2.4 GHz 802.11n.

ifconfig on REMOTE

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr **redacted**
          inet addr:192.168.0.253  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fe27:4fe4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:130858099 errors:0 dropped:6196 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:87190652 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:152330084160 (152.3 GB)  TX bytes:69709394766 (69.7 GB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:149614 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:149614 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:151856141 (151.8 MB)  TX bytes:151856141 (151.8 MB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  P-t-P:192.168.0.101  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1396  Metric:1
          RX packets:458 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
          RX bytes:49460 (49.4 KB)  TX bytes:146281 (146.2 KB)
```

ipconfig /all on HOME

```
PPP adapter VPN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VPN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.101(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.253
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-N 7260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : **redacted**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.16(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 14. ledna 2017 11:44:39
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 16. ledna 2017 12:42:59
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 208.67.222.222
                                       192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

**TL;DR:** On PPTP VPN the remote machine is using only third of available upload bandwidth. I want to know why.

Comment: First, [basically, PPTP is fundamentally insecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol#Security); strongly consider ditching it. Second, what is the CPU utilization like at both VPN termination points?

Comment: I know about the insecurity, but for me it's acceptable payoff for having built-in Windows client. The CPU utilization hovers around 1-3%, so nothing significant.